# Prove that |-a| = |a|

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, absolute-value

I'm struggling to understand the basic proof for the following theorem:

$\lvert -a\rvert = \lvert a \rvert$

The provided solution goes on to describe the following:

$(i)$ For $a \ge 0 $, since $-a \le 0$

$\lvert -a \rvert = -(-a)=a, \lvert a \rvert = a$

My question: Why does $\lvert -a \rvert = -(-a)$ hold true?

Comment: Are you familiar with the (more rigorous) definition of $|\cdot|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided we are working the a subring $A$, of the reals (i.e. $\mathbb{Z, Q, R}$), then the absolute value function is defined for $a \in A$ as:

\begin{equation}
    |a|=
    \begin{cases}
      -a, & \text{if}\ a<0\\
      0, & \text{if}\ a=0 \\
      a, & \text{if}\ a>0
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

So to answer your question, in the case $a \geq 0$, $|-a|=-(-a)$ comes straight from the definition, as $-a \leq 0$ (obviously noting $0=-0$).

Answer (score 4):

The definition of $|a|$ is:

$|a| := \begin{cases} a \quad a \geq 0\\ -a \quad a\leq0 \end{cases}$

So, suppose $a \geq 0$

Then, $|a| = a$

$|-a| = -(-a) = a$. Therefore, $|-a| = |a|$

Now, suppose $a \leq 0$

Then, $|a| = -a$

$|-a| = -a$

Hence, $|a| = |-a|$

So, for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we find:

$$|a| = |-a|$$

Answer (score 3):

The definition of $|\cdot|$ is:
$$|x| := \begin{cases}x & x \ge 0\\-x & x<0\end{cases}$$

So, for $a \ge 0$, since $-a\le 0$, we have $|-a| = -(-a)$, by the definition of $|\cdot|$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take -a≥0 then |-a|=-a ........(1)

```
        0<a then |a |=a  ........(2)
```

by (1) and (2) |-a|=|a |

Let's take -a<0 then |-a|=-(-a)=a .........(3)

```
        0≤a then |a |=a ...............(4)
```

by (3) and (4) |-a|=|a |

conclusion= |-a|=|a |

NOTE:The absolute value function always gives the positive value of some number.That is why the negative number -a gives the positive number -(-a) as the absolute value.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.